# How to load an uppercase alphabet?

Tags: python, uppercase, alphabet, caesar-cipher

I have been trying to create a Caesar cipher program. To make it as inclusive as possible I want to be able to use upper case letters as well. I know how to load a lower case alphabet:

```
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase * 2
```

(I have timed it by two to allow the user to encrypt all letters)
I would really like some help. It is my first time submitting a question and I would appreciate any help I get

Comment: `string.ascii_uppercase`?

Comment: I will add an if statement to determine whether the letter in the message is upper case or not

Comment: About this `if` statement of yours, you can use the [`isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) method to determine if a message is upper case or not.

Comment: string.ascii_letters provides both upper and lower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `string.ascii_uppercase` as well as `string.ascii_lowercase` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase)). For testing if a letter is upper case and do something for uppercase letters in a message you can do this:

```
for letter in message:
    if letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
        # do something
```

You can also use `isupper()` method ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)):

```
for letter in message:
    if letter.isupper():
        # do something
```

If you want to check whether the whole message is upper case, then `isupper()` is actually better as it checks the whole string:

```
if message.isupper():
    # do something
```

Comment: Thank you, you answered my next question before I asked it

Answer (score 2):

If there is a `string.ascii_lowercase` then surely there is a `string.ascii_uppercase`. Give it a try.

Comment: sorry, I need just uppercase

Comment: @KateMarron and which part od ascii_uppercase provides you with something more than uppercase?

Comment: @zubergu Sorry, I thought I had checked that! I accidentally forgot the case at the end! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use

**string.uppercase**
This is locale-dependent, and value will be updated when locale.setlocale() is called.

Please refer - https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: @kate-marron - if you could paste the code snippet as a part of question then that help to answer the question more effeciently.

Answer (score -1):

This loop will make a string with all uppercase letters and save it in *letters_str*

```
letters_str = ''
for x in range(65,91):
    letters_str+=chr(x)
```

Comment: That's just pointless, there's no need for ascii character codes to generate all uppercase letters.

Comment: I'd rather you put `string.ascii_lowercase.upper()` than see you try this.

Comment: What the question to be answered?